# ¿por qué me retorna que el 15 es un número primo, cuando no lo es?

Tags: javascript

buen día, estoy haciendo ejercicios de javaScript, donde el usuario digita un número y en una caja de texto se le dice si es primo oh no. la cosa es que no se por que me dice que el 15 es número primo, si no lo es. ya revise muchas veces el código.

ustedes que tienen más experiencia. ¿me pueden ayudar?

aquí evaluó lo que me mandan.

```
<script>
        function evaluar() {
            var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value);
            var res = "";
            
            if (numero === 0) {
                res = "no es primo";
            } else {
                var limite = Math.round(Math.sqrt(numero));
                for (let x = 2; x <= limite; x++) {
                    if (numero % x === 0) {
                        res = "no es primo";
                    }else{
                        res = "es primo";   
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("resultado").value = res;
        }
    </script>
```

algo así me sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: Hola Lemuel, cambia ***var res = "";*** por ***var res = "es primo";***, agrega en el primer ***if***, una condición para número igual a "1", quita el ***else***, i boileau!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque tu for sigue ejecutándose, tienes que tu valor es 15, por tanto

- limite = 4

en el for, cuando x =3, te da que `no es primo`, pero luego sigue y ahora con x=4, te pisa el resultado arrojando que `es primo` (porque 15 no es divisible por 4)

En otras palabras, tu for no sirve de nada, porque siempre se queda con el último resultado.

Sugiero además que dividas al función en 2: Una que evalúa y otra que entrega los mensajes. Me gusta separar responsabilidades

Ejemplo

```js
function esPrimo(numero) {
    if (numero === 0) {
        return false;
    } 
    var limite = Math.round(Math.sqrt(numero));
    for (let x = 2; x <= limite; x++) {
        if (numero % x === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}   

function evaluar() {
    var numero = Number(document.getElementById("numero").value);
   
   if(esPrimo(numero)){
     document.getElementById("resultado").value = "es primo";
   }
   else{
     document.getElementById("resultado").value = "no es primo";
   }
   
    
}
```

```html
<input id="numero">
<button onclick="evaluar()">evaluar</button>
<input id="resultado">
```

Fíjate como gracias al return, podemos parar el for. Otra alternativa podría haber sido usar un `break`

Comment: `brake` o `break`?

Comment: co combo breaker

Comment: @Yussef  ohhhh muchas gracias :)
una cosa... por que pusiste doble ; aqui ? 
return false;;

Comment: @lemuelAyanotfuentesAyala Error de tipeo :P ..... pero ahora sabes que un doble `;;` no afecta en nada. Que bueno te haya servido la explicación

Answer (score 2):

Resulta que cuando el bucle `for` encuentra un divisor del número y establece `res` en `no es primo`, pero cuando no encuentra un divisor en ese momento, establece `res` en `es primo`, en la cual no es correcto ya que el bucle debe continuar verificando todos los posibles divisores antes de determinar si el número es primo o no.

En pocas palabras, tu `for` siempre va a quedar con el último resultado. Para solucionarlo, podrías indicar que `res` se establezca en `es primo` antes que entre al `for`, y cuando entre a la condición `if`, cambie el valor de `res` y rompas el ciclo con `break`, quedando así:

```
var limite = Math.round(Math.sqrt(numero));
res = "es primo";
for (let x = 2; x <= limite; x++) {
  if (numero % x === 0) {
    res = "no es primo";
    break;
  }
}
```

Código:

```js
function evaluar() {
  var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").value);
  var res = "";

  if (numero === 0) {
    res = "no es primo";
  } else {
    var limite = Math.round(Math.sqrt(numero));
    res = "es primo";
    for (let x = 2; x <= limite; x++) {
      if (numero % x === 0) {
        res = "no es primo";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").value = res;
}
```

```html
<input id="numero">
<button onclick="evaluar()">evaluar</button>
<input id="resultado">
```